# getSublistValue is not returning value

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have used getSublistValue to get and set item's internal id to other custom record's "product" field. But its setting item name to "product" field instead of item id. Please Help!

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/record','N/search','N/runtime'], function(record,search,runtime) {

    function execute(context) {
    
        try {
            var script = runtime.getCurrentScript();
            var id = script.getParameter({name: 'custscript_qa_record_id'});
            var type = script.getParameter({name: 'custscript_qa_record_type'});
            log.debug('i_qa_record_id:', id+',i_qa_record_type='+type);

              if(id && type)
              {
                  var REC;
                  var quote = record.load({type: type, id: id});
                  log.debug('quote:==',quote);
                  var customer = quote.getValue({fieldId: 'entity'});
                  log.debug('customer:==',customer);
                                 

                  var lineCount = quote.getLineCount({sublistId: 'item'});
                                                   
                  for(var cnt=0; cnt<lineCount; cnt++)
                  {
                      var i_quote = quote.getSublistValue({sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'custcol_far_trn_relatedasset', line: cnt}); 
                      var item_1 = quote.getSublistValue({sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'item', line: cnt});
                      log.debug('item_1===',item_1);    
                                              
                          
                      if(i_quote)
                      {
                                                 
                          REC.setValue({fieldId: 'custrecord_products', value:item_1 });
                         
                  }//end of for(var cnt=0; cnt<lineCount; cnt++)
                  var i_id = quote.save({enableSourcing: true, ignoreMandatoryFields: true});
                  log.debug('i_id:=== '+i_id);
            }//end of if(id && type)    
           
            
        }catch (error) {
            log.debug('Error', error);
           }    
       
    }
    return {
        execute: execute
    };
});
```

Script is  Not setting item's internal Id.

Comment: can you actually supply the code? The originally pasted code has unmatched braces and sets a value on `REC` but rec is undefined at the time of first use.  What type of field is `custrecord_products` ?

Comment: I have to set quote's items name to 'item name' field on custom record which sets properly and item id to 'product' field which is list type. but my code is setting item name to 'product' field instead of item id.

Answer (score 0):

According to the SuiteScript Record Browser, the **item** sublist of the Quote (or Estimate in NetSuite standard names) has a bunch of fields accessible from the script.

I believe you should use the **item** field. I ran a code snippet that does what you need using the debugger and this is what I got.

[image]

The *item* that I'm trying to get here has an *internalid* of 43. As shown from the Local Variables tab, *item* was assigned the value of 43.

Conclusion: The **item** field gives you the item's internal id which is what I understand is what you're asking.

Comment: I have to set quote's  items name to 'item name' field on custom record and item id to 'product' field which is list type. but my code is setting item name to 'product' field instead of item id.

Comment: I don't see any 'product' field being set from your code. Is 'custrecord_products' where you should set the item id?

Comment: yes, 'custrecord_products' is product

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the record after you've ran the code. It would also help to share the custom record's definition. If 'custrecord_products' type is list type, it would appear as the Item Name on the UI when you've successfully set the item id.